# PHP get class reference of an object

Tags: php

for instance

I've a class called Ent, and have an object $ent

how can I get the class Ent out of $ent?

```
$ent =    new Ent()
```

Comment: what do u mean by OUT OF ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get_class(new Ent())
```

this will even work in earlier versions of PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_class($ent)`

get_class - Returns the name of the class of an object

**Reference** [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ent = new Ent();    
$my_class = get_class($ent);
$new_ent = new $my_class;
```

**RTM:** [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

Answer (score 0):

You could get `get_class()`.

Watch out though, if your calling it on a variable that might not be an object it will throw a warning.

```
if(is_object($ent))
{
    $class = get_class($ent);
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php